# Javascript: Generate random numbers with fixed mean and standard deviation

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

**My question:**

How can I create a list of random numbers with a given mean and standard deviation (sd) in Javascript?

**Example:**

I want to create a list with 5 random numbers in a range between 1 to 10. The resulting mean should be 5 and the standard deviation should be 2.

**What I've done so far:**

My idea was (http://jsfiddle.net/QASDG/3/):

1. Make a function (named "createData") which creates 5 random numbers between 1 and 10 and push them into an "array"
2. This function should also calculate the mean (and the sd) of those 5 numbers.
3. With a "do-while"-loop: Do the above function as long as the "average becomes 5" (and "sd becomes 2"). But when I call the do-while Loop, the browser crashes of course because there are a lot of cases when the average is != 5 (and the sd != 2).

Note: I haven't add the SD yet, since the code isn't very elegant.

I've found another script from this site which stated: "The goal of this code is to generate a collection filled with 5 normally distributed random numbers with a mean of 1.0 and a standard deviation of 0.5." http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Random_numbers#JavaScript. I've tried to adjust it according to my needs by adding "Math.floor" and changed the condition in the "for"-loop (i < 5).

```
function randomNormal() {
    return Math.floor(Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * Math.random()) * Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(Math.random())))
}

var a = []
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    a[i] = randomNormal() / 2 + 1
}
```

**How I want to modify my code:**

I'm not quite sure whether I've understood the mathematical part of this code. According to the webpage it will create a normal distribution (which is great but not necessary). So what I need in addition is:

- Where can I change the given mean and sd (e.g. mean = 5, sd = 2) in order to create random numbers (which fulfill those properties).
- How do I implement the range between 1 and 10? (Maybe I could use something like: Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't `Math.floor` in that place always round to `0`?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Standard-Deviation now code. show us what have you tried then we help. I bet it's your exercise for school and to be honest it's quite interesting so for your own good **don't look for ready solution, don't ask for ready solution**

Comment: @Peter: Please re-read the question. He doesn't want to calculate standard deviation, he wants to *generate* a set that has the wanted property. Also, he *did* provide the code he tried.

Comment: @Bergi: I know. He needs to generate random numbers which match requirement mean=x,sd=y

Comment: @Peter: Then why did you comment "*show us what have you tried*" and link to http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Standard-Deviation?

Comment: I can tell you one thing. Go brute force, otherwise it's not random :D

Comment: @Bergi just before "show us what have you tried" i wrote "now code"

Comment: @Peter: I've tried something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QASDG/, but it created an (almost) infinite loop (so I didn't write it in my post). My idea was: (1) Make a function (named "createData") which creates 5 random numbers between 1 and 10 and push them into an "array" (2) This function should also calculate the mean of those 5 numbers. (3) With a "do-while"-loop: Do the above function as long as the "average = 5". But when I call the do-while Loop, the browser crashed of course, because there are a lot of cases, when the average is != 5. (Nevertheless I'll edit this answer to my post).

Comment: @OhDaeSu: It seems to me it is not possible to find 5 integers in a range between 1 to 10 with the mean = 5 and the sd = 2. Is it possible in your case to set the sd not as a number, but as a range?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How can I create a list of random numbers with a given mean and standard deviation (sd) in JavaScript?

This appears to be a question about randomly creating a list of numbers that has an exactly specified [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) and an exactly specified [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) (and not a question about drawing random numbers from a specific probability distribution with a given mean and sd).

A straightforward solution is to draw a list of random numbers, then to shift and scale this list to have the desired mean and sd, as [described in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30311/160753) from *stats.stackexchange*.

Say, we generate the following 5 random numbers between 1 and 10:

```
4.527991433628388
6.3254986488276055
5.123502737960912
7.3331068522336125
9.069573681037484
```

This list has a mean of `6.475934670737601` and sd of `1.8102412442104023`.

Then, we transform each number in the list like this:

```
newNum = newSD * (oldNum - oldMean) / oldSD + newMean
```

By setting the new mean to 5 and new sd to 2, we get the following transformed list:

```
2.847863379160965
4.83379450402964
3.505799227476338
5.947025358346529
7.865517530986525
```

Computing the mean and sd of this list confirms that they are indeed 5 and 2.

Below is code demonstrating this approach in JavaScript:

```js
// create a list of 5 random numbers between 1 and 10
var list = randomList(5, 1, 10);

// transform the list to have an exact mean of 5 and sd of 2
var newList = forceDescriptives(list, 5, 2);

// display the transformed list and descriptive statistics (mean and sd)
console.log('Transformed random list', newList, descriptives(newList));

// display the original list and descriptive statistics (mean and sd)
console.log('Original random list', list, descriptives(list));


/* demo functions */

function randomList(n, a, b) {
  // create a list of n numbers between a and b
  var list = [],
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    list[i] = Math.random() * (b - a) + a;
  }
  return list;
}

function descriptives(list) {
  // compute mean, sd and the interval range: [min, max]
  var mean,
    sd,
    i,
    len = list.length,
    sum,
    a = Infinity,
    b = -a;
  for (sum = i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += list[i];
    a = Math.min(a, list[i]);
    b = Math.max(b, list[i]);
  }
  mean = sum / len;
  for (sum = i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += (list[i] - mean) * (list[i] - mean);
  }
  sd = Math.sqrt(sum / (len - 1));
  return {
    mean: mean,
    sd: sd,
    range: [a, b]
  };
}

function forceDescriptives(list, mean, sd) {
  // transfom a list to have an exact mean and sd
  var oldDescriptives = descriptives(list),
    oldMean = oldDescriptives.mean,
    oldSD = oldDescriptives.sd,
    newList = [],
    len = list.length,
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    newList[i] = sd * (list[i] - oldMean) / oldSD + mean;
  }
  return newList;
}
```

#### Limitations

Note that, due to precision limits in floating-point arithmetic, the demo sometimes computes the exact mean and sd to deviate slightly (like an sd of `2.0000000000000004` instead of `2`). Also note that, depending on the desired mean and sd, it may not be possible to generate a list of numbers within a desired range, as described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1303928/388113) on *math.stackexchange*. This means that the transformed list could be in a very different range than the original list. Also note that it is likely not possible to generate lists of random integers from a given range with a given integer mean and integer sd.

Comment: Excellent answer, but the code really hurts my eyes. I've 'modernized' it a little bit (see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plantface/0mg3ns5n/)).

Comment: @BennyBottema, nice example of the benefits of ES6. I usually write ES3 compliant code unless I know where it will be used. Sorry if that hurts your eyes ...

Comment: Not to worry, here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plantface/oL2m1t7t/) that works with the 18 years old spec that is ES3. I guess if it works in IE5 it's good enough, right?

Comment: This is a wonderful answer that covers the topic thoroughly and adequately. And seeing as how it's also the _only_ one, it's deserving of the bounty. Thanks for responding to that call for action!