# Generate random numbers from a normal distribution with fixed mean, SD and range in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random, normal-distribution

I learned how to generate a list of random numbers with fixated range, mean and sd from this answer [Javascript: Generate random numbers with fixed mean and standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619719/javascript-generate-random-numbers-with-fixed-mean-and-standard-deviation),  yet I also learned that math.random() does not follow a normal distribution. My problem is if it is possible to generate a list of random numbers following a normal distribution with a fixed range, mean and sd in JavaScript? i.e., randomly draw 10 numbers from a normal distribution ranging from 2 to 100; the mean should be 20 and sd should be 10?

for the normal distribution part, I have tried this to draw random numbers (0 to 1) from a normal distribution, in order to replace the Math.random() function:

```
function randn_normal() {
    var u = 0, v = 0;
    while (u === 0) u = Math.random(); //Converting [0,1) to (0,1)
    while (v === 0) v = Math.random();
    let num = Math.sqrt(-2.0 * Math.log(u)) * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * v);
    num = num / 10.0 + 0.5; // Translate to 0 -> 1
    if (num > 1 || num < 0) return randn_normal(); // resample between 0 and 1
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - generate random numbers following normal distribution within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618900/c-generate-random-numbers-following-normal-distribution-within-range)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191417/choosing-from-a-range-of-numbers-with-normal-distribution/45193928#45193928